# uniqueness of struct names

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

While the name of a structure must be unique in the set of structures within a namespace, such a name can be "shared" with variables and functions. For example, the following code compiles just fine:

```
// Code 1
struct h{};
int h{ 8 };
```

Similarly, there is no collision in:

```
// Code 2
struct h{};
void h(){}
```

**1) What was the reasoning to allow that name sharing?**

Moreover, if we throw templates into the mix, we have some strange situations. The code

```
// Code 3
template< class H > void h(){}
struct h{};
template< class H > struct j{};
void j(){}
```

does compile; but the following code fails:

```
// Code 4
struct h{};
template< class H > void h(){}
void j(){}
template< class H > struct j{};
```

**2) Why the reasoning that allowed code 2 was not good enough to allow code 4?** I am not asking about the rules in the standard. I am asking about the reason behind those rules.

Comment: 1) Compatibility with C, where you'd have to use `struct h` to refer to the struct. Unix headers (`stat.h`) use it, so it had to be supported in C++ as well and couldn't be removed (source: D&E 2.8.2).

Comment: ["The Design and Evolution of C++"](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html), by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Both code 3 and code 4 are rejected by clang++. However, just the `template<class> void h(){} struct h{};` is accepted by clang++. Which compiler + version did you use for your tests?

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't expect that 3 and 4 would produce different results.

Comment: Code 3 was accepted by MSVC2015.

Comment: In my opinion, even the part `template<class> void h(){} struct h{};` is illegal according to [temp]p5: *[...] Except that a
function template can be overloaded either by non-template functions with the same name or by other function templates with the same name, a template name declared in namespace scope or in class scope shall be unique in that scope."*

Comment: Therefore, I guess the rationale for 2) is that this feature could be removed when templates are involved, as there's no compatibility issue with C in those cases.

Comment: Reported as a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1597935).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **1) What was the reasoning to allow that name sharing?**

According to ["The Design and Evolution of C++", by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html), section 2.8.2 "Structure Tags vs. Type Names", this feature was introduced to maintain compatibility with C. The C language requires the use of the `struct` keyword to name a structure (no keyword is required to name a typedef). You can then use the same identifier to declare a structure and either a function or a variable:

```
struct X { int m; };
void X(void);

X(); // call X
struct X x; // create a new object of type X
```

> A significant syntactic simplification for the benefit of users was
>   introduced into C++ at the cost of some extra work to implementers and
>   some C compatibility problems. [...] In the context of C with Classes
>   [dyp: the predecessor of C++], this had annoyed me for some time
>   because it made user-defined types second-class citizens
>   syntactically.
>
> [...]
>
> The real need to address this particular issue came from the fact that some standard UNIX header files, notably, `stat.h`, rely on a `struct` and a variable or function having the same name.
>
> -- *D&E 2.8.2*

---

> **2) Why the reasoning that allowed code 2 was not good enough to allow code 4?**

I'll first quote the C++11 Standard:

> A class template shall not have the same name as any other template,
>   class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type
>   in the same scope (3.3), except as specified in (14.5.5 *[dyp: class template partial specialization]*). Except that
>   a function template can be overloaded either by (non-template)
>   functions with the same name or by other function templates with the
>   same name (14.8.3 *[dyp: this refers to overloading]*), a template name declared in namespace scope or in
>   class scope shall be unique in that scope.
>
> -- *C++11 International Standard [temp]p5*

According to my interpretation of this passage, codes 3 and 4 are both illegal. clang++ rejects them, but accepts the first part of code 3:

```
template< class H > void h(){}
struct h{};
```

Which, according to [temp]p5, should be illegal as well.

Considering all these examples (3, 4, and the beginning of 3) as illegal, I think the *rationale* is that you don't need the compatibility exception in those cases: C has no templates.